# Angular to submit second form after first form validation/promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, submit

I'm submitting a form with an update() function in Angular, which then authenticates, returns a promise, and then submits a second form if successful.

The problem is, the second form won't submit with the document.getElementById(elementID).submit(); method. It will, however, submit with document.getElementById(elementID).click(); but only on non-touch devices of course.

Bottom line - why won't submit() work?

Here is a jsFiddle with a reduced and simplified version: http://jsfiddle.net/jimcamut/xos805gk/

Here is my function that handles the form submissions in its full version.

```
$scope.update = function(user) {

        if ($scope.earlyUser.$valid) {
            $scope.master = angular.copy(user);

            console.log("Form submitted on front end");


            // This integrates ParseJS and submits the data to a database - all good here, except after the promise
            var parseUser = new Parse.Object("LaunchUser");
            parseUser.setACL(new Parse.ACL());
            parseUser.save({
                name: $scope.master.name,
                email: $scope.master.email,
                zipcode: $scope.master.zipcode
            },{
                error: function(model, error) {
                    console.log("error is...");
                    console.log(error);
                }

            // Returns a promise
            }).then(function(object) {


                // Problem area here when attempting to submit second form...
                document.getElementById('mc-embedded-subscribe').submit();



                $scope.reset();
            });

        } else {
            alert("Please correct the red form fields.");
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you reduce the example the simple as possible and make a fiddle. It will be better for clarification.

Comment: @Lautaro Cozzani, here is a reduced version: http://jsfiddle.net/jimcamut/xos805gk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

element with id='mc-embedded-subscribe' is an input, but you need to "submit()" a form. 
this line

```
document.getElementById('mc-embedded-subscribe').submit();
```

should be changed for

```
document.getElementById('mc-embedded-subscribe-form').submit();
```

Here you have a new fiddle with this changes, and it works!
http://jsfiddle.net/kx8dn8wc/

Comment: An important detail I overlooked caused a couple hours of frustration. Thanks for the patience to look at this and the keen eye!

Comment: Great, 4 eyes watch better than two